# MVC internal working PHP

Tags: model-view-controller

I have basically the following folder structure:

```
Framework_Folder
    |__application
    |     |_Models
    |     |_views
    |     |_controllers
    |
    |__config
    |__core
    |     |
    |     |_model.php
    |     |_controller.php
    |     |_bootstrap.php
    |     |_security.php
    |
    |__index.php
    |__.htaccess
```

I do this way: 
I redirect all http request to index.php using .htaccess
Index.php set up Absolute paths and loads bootstrap.php
bootstrap.php loads security (which turns of global register, magic quotes et al) and loads the required controller

I wonder if theoreticall there is something Iam missing or I'm doing wrong before I put to test this design. Also any suggestion of anything to add or remove is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using same structure with little modification to accomodate templates. Else, it is perfect structure, at least for me!